# How to do basic math with FIGURE counter in PDF bookmarks

Tags: hyperref, pdf, bookmarks

I'm preparing a document (`revtex4-1` class) with figures. I'd like to have bookmark for each figure in the PDF, so I use `hyperref` with the following command that inserts figures:

```
\newcommand{\AddFigureLabelContentCaption}[3]{{
\clearpage
\begin{figure}[t]
\currentpdfbookmark{Figure \arabic{figure}}{name:#1}
{#2}
\caption{#3}
\label{#1}
%\currentpdfbookmark{Figure \thefigure~[++]}{name:#1}
\end{figure}
}}
```

Everything is OK, but figure numbers start from zero. When I move the `\currentpdfbookmark` command after the `label` command, figure numbers in PDF bookmarks are OK. But clicking on the bookmark sends me right after the figure, which is not good.

Is it possible to output not the `figure` counter, but `figure+1`? I do not want to mess the `figure` counter, I just want to output a `figure+1`.

Comment: You can use: `Figure \the\numexpr\arabic{figure}+1\relax` or you can load the package `hypcap`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`\thefigure` can print a complex figure number and is not available for calculations in general (e.g. `1.4`, `(a)`, ...). A trick is to update the `figure` counter and reset it afterwards:

```
\stepcounter{figure}%
\currentpdfbookmark{Figure \thefigure}{name:#1}%
\addtocounter{figure}{-1}%
```

### Package `bookmark`

- The destination that is generated by `\caption` can be used for the bookmark, if package `bookmark` is used. Internally `hyperref` stores this in macro `\@currentHref`. (Currently package `bookmark` does not provide the feature of extracting the destination name from a label.)
- Also I would put the figure bookmarks a level deeper than the current level
  without changing the current level afterwards.
- Package `caption` (or `hypcap`) puts the anchor at the top of the figure instead to the location of `\caption` that usually goes below the actual figure.

Example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{bookmark}
\bookmarksetup{
  numbered,
  open,
}
\begin{document}
\section{Hello World}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\fbox{\phantom{\rule{50mm}{10mm}}}
\caption{My caption}
\label{fig:my}
\bookmark[   
  rellevel=1,
  keeplevel=false,
  dest=\csname @currentHref\endcsname,
]{Figure \thefigure: My caption}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```